# How to insert object that hasn't been defined in a loop that does define it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, object

I have the next object. This is used to make calls to an API and get data.

```
const extractorData = [
  {
    name: 'newshub',
    link: 'https://direct.faforever.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=100&_embed&_fields=_links.author,_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded,title,content.rendered,date,categories&categories=587',
    sortingCriteria: {
      date: item.date,
      title: item.title.rendered,
      content: item.content.rendered,
      author: item._embedded.author[0].name,
      media: item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url,
    },
  },
];
```

in my code, the 'item' variable hasn't been defined yet. It is defined in this loop.

```
let data = dataObjectToArray.map(item => ({
    date: item.date,
    title: item.title.rendered,
    content: item.content.rendered,
    author: item._embedded.author[0].name,
    media: item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url,
  }));
```

'item' simply is the naming convention for each item inside 'dataObjectToArray'. However, I re-use this piece of code a lot (while changing the sorting parameters such as date, title, etc). Therefore, I want to put these parameters into an object and just cycle through the objects with the parameters rather than repeating the same line of code multiple times.

The issue is since 'item' isn't defined, JS throws an error about how item isn't defined on extractorData. I've tried putting the 'item.date' into a string but then it stays a string. What could be a solution to being able to insert this object into the loop/.map  correctly? Thanks!

Here is what the code should look like, but it doesnt work because item isn't defined in extractorData.

```
 let data = dataObjectToArray.map((item, index) => (
    extractorData[index].sortingCriteria
  ));
```

EDIT:

This produces the next error:

```
ReferenceError: item is not defined
```

It references to this line of code, because item isn't defined in the code.

```
 sortingCriteria: {
      date: item.date, <=== ERROR
      title: item.title.rendered,
      content: item.content.rendered,
      author: item._embedded.author[0].name,
      media: item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url,
    },
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding.  Can you edit the question to present a snippet of code that produces an error, and quote the error exactly?  In the last bit of code in the question, item *is certainly defined* inside the map function. So is `index`. What might not be defined is `extractorData[index]` or the `sortingCriteria` property of that thing.

Comment: How do you know that an index from dataObjectToArray even exists in extractorData?

Comment: I just did an edit. I just want to know how can I put 'item' in the object without defining it yet and js not breaking/crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to configure via the `sortingCriteria` object which nested values from an `item` object should be collected into a new object, which follows the `sortingCriteria` template.

You cannot reference `item` in `sortingCriteria`, but you can list the *path* of keys to follow in it:

```
const extractorData = {
    name: 'newshub',
    link: 'https://direct.faforever.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=100&_embed&_fields=_links.author,_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded,title,content.rendered,date,categories&categories=587',
    sortingCriteria: {
        date: ["date"],
        title: ["title", "rendered"],
        content: ["content", "rendered"],
        author: ["_embedded", "author", 0, "name"],
        media: ["_embedded", "wp:featuredmedia", 0, "source_url"],
    },
};
```

Then the callback to your `map` function should follow those paths in their `item` object to retrieve the corresponding value. The functions `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` can serve in that process:

```
const data = dataObjectToArray.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(extractorData.sortingCriteria).map(([k, path]) =>
        [k, path.reduce((acc, key) => acc?.[key], item)]
    )
));
```

Here is a demo using an array with one data object:

```js
const extractorData = {
    name: 'newshub',
    link: 'https://direct.faforever.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=100&_embed&_fields=_links.author,_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded,title,content.rendered,date,categories&categories=587',
    sortingCriteria: {
        date: ["date"],
        title: ["title", "rendered"],
        content: ["content", "rendered"],
        author: ["_embedded", "author", 0, "name"],
        media: ["_embedded", "wp:featuredmedia", 0, "source_url"],
    },
};

// Sample data
const dataObjectToArray = [{
    date: "2000-02-01",
    title: { rendered: "mytitle" },
    content: { rendered: "mycontent" },
    _embedded: { 
        author: [{ name: "Jen" }],
        ["wp:featuredmedia"]: [{ source_url: "http" }]
    }
}];

const data = dataObjectToArray.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(extractorData.sortingCriteria).map(([k, path]) =>
        [k, path.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], item)]
    )
));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Extremely appreciated!